# Detect process if not found then run it

Tags: process, monitoring, startup, services

I am running several process at startup using "crontab -e"

```
@reboot tranmission-daemon && python defualt.py && python MonitorService.py
```

But for some reason, those service can terminate by itself due to hdd insufficient, or web host killed it, how do I check if those service are killed and I re run it again?

I am using CentOS 6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend supervisord (supervisord dot org) which happens to be written in Python.

Here is an article for installing it using the Python package manager: [Herd Unix Processes with Supervisor](http://stackful-dev.com/simplify-unix-process-herding-with-supervisor.html).

If you would rather use RPM, then use this guide: [Running supervisor 3 on CentOS 5](http://www.g-loaded.eu/2011/05/12/running-supervisor-3-on-centos-5/)

Hit back if you have any issues. It's a great tool once you get it working.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure about your python scripts but the transmission application includes a init.d service that you should be starting rather than doing something custom such as starting it via a crontab entry.

You can check to see if the transmission service is configured to start in any of your system's runlevels.

#### Example

```
$ chkconfig --list | grep transm
transmission-daemon 0:off   1:off   2:off   3:off   4:off   5:off   6:off
```

If they're off then yo can change them so that they'll start upon reboot like so:

```
$ sudo chkconfig --level 345 transmission-daemon on
```

Now when we check you should see that its configured to start on runlevels 3,4, & 5.

```
$ sudo chkconfig --list | grep transm
transmission-daemon 0:off   1:off   2:off   3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
```

This will take care of starting it the next time you reboot. To start it now without having to reboot your system you can do so like this:

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/transmission-daemon start
Starting transmission-daemon:                              [  OK  ]
$
```

#### Other scripts

If you want to make sure that the Python scripts stay up you can create another crontab entry that periodically checks to see if they're running, and if not start them up. Or you could abandon the `@reboot` crontab entry all together and just have a single crontab entry that periodically checks if they're running, and restart them if they die.

#### Example

Under `/etc/cron.d` you can create a file, `chkr.cron`, like this:

```
*/5 * * * * root /usr/local/bin/chkr.bash
```

Then create the script `/usr/local/bin/chkr.bash` which would look like this.

```
#!/bin/bash

pgrep -f "python default.py"       || python default.py
pgrep -f "python MonitorService.py || python MonitorService.py
```

Answer (score 0):

Install monit. It's easy to configure and can check for processes and restart them if they are not there.